# Tracing outline landsat with python

Tags: python, gdal

How to do it http://blog.remotesensing.io/2014/06/tracing-raster-outlines-with-gdal/ without necessity to save shapefile. I would like to return only polyton geometry.

```
gdal_trace_outline -ndv 0 -out-cs en -dp-toler 10 -ogr-out outline.shp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual linked](https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts/wiki/Gdal_trace_outline) in the page that you are referencing, you can see that there are a number of different output methods:

```
Output:
  -report fn.ppm               Output graphical report of polygons found
  -mask-out fn.pbm             Output mask of bounding polygon in PBM format
  -out-cs [xy | en | ll]       Set coordinate system for following outputs
                               (pixel coords, easting/northing, or lon/lat)
                               Must be specified before -{wkt,wkb,ogr}-out options
  -llproj-toler val            Error tolerance for curved lines when
                               using '-out-cs ll' (in pixels, default is 1.0)
  -wkt-out fn.wkt              Output polygons in WKT format
  -wkb-out fn.wkb              Output polygons in WKB format
  -ogr-out fn.shp              Output polygons using an OGR format
```

The choice depends on how you are planning on interacting with the results, but WKT seems like a simple solution. However, the script does seem aimed at creating files, not reporting back to the commandline.

Comment: I wouldn't like to save any kind of format. I think to keep polygon (wkt) in memory to use it immediately.